# Help bulkifying a simple trigger

Tags: trigger, map, bulkification

I'm trying to create a trigger that sets a case status to "closed" if there are more than 2 cases created that day associated with the same contact. 
This is so far what I have written, but I'm getting a null pointer exception on line 33  (`if(myRelatedCases.size() > 1)`).

```
trigger CloseCase on Case (before insert) {

    //Creating a List to store all the records in trigger.new
    List<String> ids = new List<String>();

    //Adding all the IDs to List<String> ids
    for(Case myCase : Trigger.new) {
        if(myCase.ContactId != null) {
            ids.add(myCase.ContactId);
        }

    }

    //Query all the cases Created today with a ContactId contained ids list
    List<Case> relatedCases = [SELECT Id, Status FROM Case
                                                      WHERE ContactId in :ids AND CreatedDate = TODAY];

    //Create a map of id to list of cases created today (Originally I was working with the email)
    Map<String,List<Case>> emailToCase = new Map<String, List<Case>>();

    //Looping the relatedCases list and add the records to the emailToCase map
    for(Case theCase : relatedCases) {
        if(!emailToCase.containsKey(theCase.ContactId)) {
            emailToCase.put(theCase.ContactId, new List<Case>() );
        }
        List<Case> entries = emailToCase.get(theCase.ContactId);
        entries.add(theCase);
    }

    //Loop my list of cases in trigger.new and get the amount of cases created today
    for(Case myCase : Trigger.new) {
        List<Case> myRelatedCases = emailToCase.get(myCase.ContactId);
        if(myRelatedCases.size() > 1) {
            myCase.Status = 'Closed';
        }       
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is going to happen every time you get a Case whose Contact has no other Cases that match the query

```
SELECT Id, Status FROM Case WHERE ContactId in :ids AND CreatedDate = TODAY
```

You populate an entry in `emailToCase` for each Contact whose `Id` comes up in the Cases that are returned by this query. But, as your code is showing you, there must always be a first Case for any given Contact on some day, and there won't be any results from the query.

As a result, `emailToCase.get(someContactId)` will return `null`, which is assigned to `myRelatedCases`. When you call `myRelatedCases.size()`, the `NullPointerException` ensues.

Simple fix? Check if it's `null` first.

```
    if(myRelatedCases != null && myRelatedCases.size() > 1) {
```

Short-circuit evaluation ensures that if `myRelatedCases` is `null`, `myRelatedCases.size()` will never be called, and you're safe from the `NullPointerException`.

Your code is already bulkified effectively and will use exactly 1 SOQL and 0 DML per trigger invocation.